# Elementary question about derivative

Tags: derivatives

i'm dealing with a really simple question that I'm struggling to find an answer because I'm messed up with physics notations. Suppose you have the relation $x=Ky$ and you have a function $f$.  $K$ is a fixed scalar. You know explicitly $f$ as well as
$$
f'\left(x\right)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(x\right)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(Ky\right)
$$
I just want to find
$$
\frac{\partial f }{\partial y}\left(x\right)
$$
in terms of $x$, is it right to write
$$
\frac{\partial f }{\partial y}\left(x\right)=K\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\left(x\right) \ \ \ ?
$$

Comment: $\frac{\partial f }{\partial y}\left(x\right)$ uses partial derivatives, and seems to ask what is the rate of change of $f(x)$ with respect to $y$ if $x$ is held constant, despite knowing $y=Kx$.

Answer (score 1):

What you are having is (in clearer notation) $f(g(y))$, where $f(x)$ is 'some' function, and $g(y)=Ky$. So you only have to apply the chain rule
$$
\frac{d}{dy}f(g(y)) = f'(x)\Big|_{x=y} g'(y) = K f'(x)\Big|_{x=y} 
$$
Note that you don't need partial derivatives, because everything is a function of a single variable. Note also that $f'(x)\Big|_{x=y} $ is often abbreviated into $f'(y)$.... but perhaps this way it's clearer.

Comment: Can you detail what is $f'(x)\Big|_{x=y} $ please ?

Comment: It is the derivative of $f(x)$ with respect to its argument, evaluated at $x = y$. For example, if $f(x)=x^2-x$, then $f'(x) = 2x-1$, and $f'(x)\Big|_{x=y}=2y-1$

Comment: Oh ok, thanks !